# @ManyToMany relationship to store ids only, without any extra columns and references to objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am looking for the best mapping design for this use case:

All I need to do is store foreign key references in a @ManyToMany relationship, but in the fetch, I do not care about objects, only id references.
I have a User and a Restaurant relationship:
Users can "like" the restaurants, and Restaurants can be "liked" by users.
In my front-end, I need to provide users the ability to store their likes and fetch them later.

This is what I've come to so far:

```
@Entity
User

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_favorite_restaurants",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "restaurant_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Set<Restaurant> userFavoriteRestaurants = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="user_favorite_restaurants",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @Column(name="restaurant_id")
    public Set<Long> restaurantIds;
```

```
@Entity
Restaurant

   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userFavoriteRestaurants")
   public Set<User> usersFavorite;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="user_favorite_restaurants",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   @Column(name="user_id")
   public Set<Long> userIds;
```

Table userFavoriteRestaurants is a simple two-column table with user_id and restaurant_id.

This does **NOT** work. userFavouriteRestaurants has a duplicate ManyToMany intersection table user_favorite_restaurants.

**Is this the way to go, or am I shooting myself in the foot down the line?
Should I just create an entity UserRestaurant and create a table with PK, or is this a good path to the solution?**

How do I return only ids, in an optimized way?

*Bonus:*
Is it logical to assume this relationship will be expanded over time and so that UserRestaurant Entity is needed sooner before later?

Comment: If you still have other doubts/questions on Hibernate beyond this one, then feel free to either search SO or ask another question `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `@ElementCollection` fields in both entities seem unnecessary to me.  Just use:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_favorite_restaurants",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "restaurant_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Set<Restaurant> userFavoriteRestaurants = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Restaurant {
    private Long id;

   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userFavoriteRestaurants")
   public Set<User> usersFavorite;
}
```

The `@ManyToMany` mapping defined in the `User` entity will create a *junction* table looking like:

```
user_id | restaurant_id
...     | ...
```

That is, Hibernate/JPA will create this junction table under the hood to automatically store the relationships between `id` values from `User` and `id` values from `Restaurant`.  You do *not* need to manage this yourself.

Comment: Ok, but I did that to easily fetch only Set of Ids, without the need for a whole object. How do I create a HashSet of Ids? Iterate over each record and add the id? Is that the optimized way?

Comment: Not sure what else you need, but it sounds like a different question.

Comment: I think it's related because in your solution I will receive Json upon fetch with the whole object inside it, not only Set of foreign keys.

Comment: @camel38 Maybe you have some confusion on how to use Hibernate.  Typically, the unit of work in Hibernate/JPA is an _entity_ (i.e. a Java object), not a primary or foreign key.  If you really did need to use the PK/FK directly, you could access them with getters, but most of the time you probably won't need that.

Comment: I understand, I was reaching for something hibernate was not designed to do. 
Thank you Tim!